# Ubuntu 18 to 20 upgrade problem (An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. )

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I have tried to upgrade for ubuntu 18 to 20 by [this](https://www.linuxtechi.com/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-ubuntu-20-04-lts/) isntruction.

And done some parts of that instruction like this:

```
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt upgrade -y
[sudo] password for so: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ sudo apt --purge autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ $ sudo apt install update-manager-core -y
$: command not found
(base) so@so-notebook:~$  sudo apt install update-manager-core -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:18.04.11.12).
update-manager-core set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

but when i run this command;

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

I get this error:

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,342 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
Get:1 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [685 kB]
Get:3 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [951 kB]
Get:4 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [306 kB]
Get:5 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,077 kB]
Get:6 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,077 kB]
Get:7 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,077 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Get:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]         
Get:10 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,077 kB]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates InRelease                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign http://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic InRelease                            
Hit http://apt.keepsolid.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                           
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Err https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                  
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.204.89.126 443]                                      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Err http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages  
  Hash Sum mismatch
Hashes of expected file:
 - Filesize:1076852 [weak]
 - SHA256:6fb0b01277f075a635caaea91c90d7737abca81571553d9adb994c6c199ba6b3
 - SHA1:8c8aacee3ec43b9465d53d38a5fccac4eb4df539 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:08335541a1b566fdc1dfe813ee608f64 [weak]
Hashes of received file:
 - SHA256:b7ae0d9c731fad8337a6e5a9e287127e112ca923c80eff1ced49c5233234db9e
 - SHA1:f02ab0ace6245d6e64a17acce1d2e2f6f617f6e2 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:202ee76128028fb0aa16456af288dae9 [weak]
 - Filesize:1076852 [weak]
Last modification reported: Thu, 04 Jun 2020 13:09:44 +0000
Release file created at: Thu, 04 Jun 2020 13:53:49 +0000

Hit https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Get:11 https://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./ InRelease [1,031 B]             
Err http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                     
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Get:12 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2,468 B]     
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [474 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/haraldhv/shotcut/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [727 kB]
Err https://shaggytwodope.github.io/repo ./ InRelease                          
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7086E9CC7EC3233B
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [43.8 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe i386 Packages [623 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [669 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/mank319/go-for-it/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit https://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu generic Release                             
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [49.2 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/slgobinath/uget-chrome-wrapper/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/tractor-team/tractor/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/lives/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/pdfocr/ubuntu bionic Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]                                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]                                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/mank319/go-for-it/ubuntu bionic Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]                                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]                                         
Fetched 3,757 kB in 6s (0 B/s)                                                 
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
No candidate ver:  torguard

Updating repository information

Third party sources disabled 

Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can 
re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool 
or your package manager. 

To continue please press [ENTER]

Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [12.1 kB]            
Get:2 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]              
Get:3 http://archive.canonical.com focal InRelease [12.1 kB]                   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]      
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal/partner Sources [1,416 B]      
Get:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal/partner amd64 Packages [1,600 B]
Get:7 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]      
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8,924 B]
Get:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal/partner i386 Packages [1,620 B]
Get:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal/partner Translation-en [804 B]
Get:11 http://archive.canonical.com focal/partner i386 Packages [1,620 B]      
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [2,516 B]
Get:13 http://archive.canonical.com focal/partner amd64 Packages [1,600 B]     
Get:14 http://archive.canonical.com focal/partner Translation-en [804 B]       
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security i386 Contents (deb) [1,288 kB]
Get:16 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse Sources [174 kB]    
Get:17 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe Sources [9,707 kB]    
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security amd64 Contents (deb) [2,698 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [31.6 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [92.7 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [35.5 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.7 kB]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [8,330 B]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [12.1 kB]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2,612 B]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,172 B]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse Translation-en [540 B]
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [9,880 B]
Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [33.0 kB]
Get:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [15.7 kB]
Get:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [31.6 kB]
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,321 B]
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [5,013 B]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1,304 B]
Get:37 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main Sources [847 kB]          
Get:38 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/restricted Sources [6,472 B]   
Get:39 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]    
Get:40 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]   
Get:41 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [506 kB]   
Get:42 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [494 kB]
Get:43 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [98.4 kB]
Get:44 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [163 kB]
Get:45 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal i386 Contents (deb) [32.2 MB]  
Get:46 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal amd64 Contents (deb) [40.9 MB] 
Get:47 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29.5 kB]
Get:48 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
Get:49 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8,628 kB]
Get:50 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,124 kB]
Get:51 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,603 kB]
Get:52 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,016 kB]
Get:53 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,794 kB]
Get:54 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [265 kB]
Get:55 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [74.7 kB]
Get:56 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Get:57 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]
Get:58 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [48.4 kB]
Get:59 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [23.1 kB]
Get:60 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [192 kB]
Get:61 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,136 B]
Get:62 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [8,112 B]
Get:63 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [22.0 kB]
Get:64 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en [6,212 B]
Get:65 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [392 B]
Get:66 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [92.8 kB]
Get:67 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:68 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [69.2 kB]
Get:69 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [102 kB]
Get:70 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [22.8 kB]
Get:71 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [37.5 kB]
Get:72 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates i386 Contents (deb) [2,638 kB]
Get:73 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates amd64 Contents (deb) [4,144 kB]
Get:74 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [5,248 B]
Get:75 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [55.0 kB]
Get:76 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [101 kB]
Get:77 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [46.4 kB]
Get:78 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [143 kB]
Get:79 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [70.3 kB]
Get:80 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [112 kB]
Get:81 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3,656 B]
Get:82 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,172 B]
Get:83 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Translation-en [540 B]
Get:84 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:85 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [8,924 B]
Get:86 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,516 B]
Get:87 http://ubuntu.unitedcolo.de/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Fetched 133 MB in 6s (388 kB/s)                                                

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

The **apt.log** file form **/var/log/dist-upgrade** folder could be seen [here](https://hastebin.com/azoqexuyaz.coffeescript) and **main.log** is also [here](https://hastebin.com/aququvilex.php).

So what do you think about this problem?

**َUpdate:**

I have done this commands also based of the comment:

```
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ apt-mark showhold

(base) so@so-notebook:~$ 
(base) so@so-notebook:~$ dpkg -l | grep "^hi"

(base) so@so-notebook:~$
```

Thanks.

Comment: `saucy`? (EOL in 2014)   Your sources show what to me are obvious problems & potential for security risks.. also loads of PPA (3rd party software sources) which directly result in the message you got, and suggested fix (ie. "*Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade again.*"  You can scan for "*breaks*" and find the actual packages that are blocking upgrade (manually), but removing all PPAs is usually quicker as automated. Or re-install (something else, no format) for the easily fastest upgrade (what I'd opt for).

Answer (score 4):

The clue is in the error-text:

```
This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.
```

So, note which PPA:s you have installed and then, if the package `ppa-purge` is not installed, then install it and use `ppa-purge` to remove all PPA-packages. Finally, retry the upgrade.

Comment: Because there are too much broken PPAs, so i asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247240/auto-remove-broken-ppa?noredirect=1#comment2103763_1247240), about auto remove PPA method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a ppa has made some conflicts with the upgrade process. It seems that you have some held packages.

Main log: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages

Maybe try the finding out what packages are being held from upgrading.

```
apt-mark showhold
```

Or by

```
dpkg -l | grep "^hi"
```

However, I would wait to upgrade until 20.04.1 has been released. When I upgraded from 18.04, I had too many boot errors which slowed my boot times to 3min+.

Comment: Nothing done by running those commands.

Comment: I tried to looking at the apt log. I can’t pin point the problem package(s). Maybe it’s one of the 62 broken packages. I think your best bet is to use ppa-purge and reinstall them after the upgrade.