# Auto remove broken ppa

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246963/ubuntu-18-to-20-upgrade-problem-an-unresolvable-problem-occurred-while-calculat?noredirect=1#comment2103307_1246963) question, i have almost 60 broken PPA based of [this](https://hastebin.com/azoqexuyaz.coffeescript) log file ( The **apt.log** file form **/var/log/dist-upgrade** folder) like this:

[image]
, so i like to know can fix it by some app to automatically remove the broken ppa from my this app:

[image]

Which i think related files are located in the **/etc/apt** folder
Thanks.

Comment: PPA shouldn't be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. thay are normally set in separate files in `/setc/apt/sources.list` directory. You can delete all there for example.

Comment: And I can't see where did you find any relation to PPA in  the log.

Comment: Thanks, @Pilot6. so i have updated the question.

Comment: There are no active ppa at all.